# Duplicate an object in array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to duplicate an object in array in mongoose.

For example, if there is a object which `projectName` is "a", I want to create a complete same one, but the name is called "a duplicated".

I tried to the following code:

```
project.find({
    "logininfo.username": username,
}, (err, users) => {
    ...
    var user= users[0];
    var dproject;
    for(var i in user.projects){
        if(user.projects[i].projectName === projectName)
        {
            dproject = user.projects[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    dproject.projectName += " duplicated";
    dproject._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    user.projects.push(dproject)
    projects.save((err, user) => {
    ...
```

However, this function will also change the previous object, which creates a completely same object (both names change to "a duplicated"), these two objects have the same `_id`.

How can I duplicate the object but keep the projectName and `_id` different?

Comment: You can generate _id of your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` to deep copy. It will make a copy but not a reference.

```
    for (var i in projects.projects) {
        if (projects.projects[i].projectName === projectName) {
            dproject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projects.projects[i])); //deep copy
            break;
        }
    }
    dproject._id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    dproject.projectName += " duplicated";
    projects.projects.push(dproject)
```